# How to include all global styles within FOLDER?

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v8

I have read through a dozen related questions on here about the Angular CLI and global styles, as well as the relevant [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/global-styles.md), but I cannot seem to find how to include a folder of styles.

My project still has the generated `styles.scss` file. I created the folder `src/styles/` and I do not wish to add an SCSS import for every file in that folder (and nested folders). The `styles` property in `angular.json` does not appear to support folders or wildcards.

I am migrating a large AngularJS project and we have many global style files. Although some of these files can be replaced with component-scoped styles, quite a few of them are for things like directive attributes and I do not know of any better way to write them.

**Is it possible to include a folder of global styles without individual imports for every file?**

Comment: I had similar situation, I solved by putting the folders (including styles) within assets folder

Comment: @dcg Will that automatically include links to all the contained styles in the HTML? Otherwise that doesn't solve the problem (having to write an include for every file).

Comment: No, I had to change where the links point

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a firm NO. Due to the nature of CSS cascade, i.e., the order in which styles get included matters, SCSS does not support importing a bunch of files in arbitrary order. You will need to write an import for each individual file so the order is explicit.